# Where can I find firebase-debug.log to understand why emulators did not cleanly shut down?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using `firebase emulators:start` to start firebase emulators. When shutting it down, through Ctrl+C, it tells me it didn't shut down correctly and that I need to consult `firebase-debug.log` which is nowhere to be found. I suspect it should be in functions/ folder where everything else related to cloud functions live, but it's not there.

```
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
i  ui: Stopping Emulator UI
⚠  Emulator UI has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  logging: Stopping Logging Emulator
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
⚠  emulators: emulators failed to shut down cleanly, see firebase-debug.log for details.
```

The problem is there is no `firebase-debug.log` to be found. Where can I find this debug file? See below contents of `functions` folder:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

`firebase-debug.log` is created in the root directory, one level up from the functions directory, beside the `firebase.json` file.

You can also launch the firebase with `--debug` flag `firebase --debug emulators:start`, in this case all debug messages will be printed into the console output.

Comment: I have looked both inside and right above the functions folder and still cannot find firebase-debug.log. I can see `firestore-debug.log`, `database-debug.log` and `ui-debug.log` in the same folder as `firebase.json`, but nothing else ‍♂️

Comment: @Zorayr you need to run `firebase init` and initialize firestore and it will generate the log file.

Comment: I ran firebase within a docker container and this file was not getting generated at the root directory; other debug logs were generated. I used the `--debug` flag as suggested and was able to view the logs at `docker container logs <container-name>`

Answer (score 1):

I found it in my Home directory and I am using Mac OS.

Comment: For those who have trouble finding it, it's located at where you run the command when it tells you to look at firebase-debug.log